# How to vectorize indexing?

Tags: r

I average coordinates stored in a data frame as follows:

```
sapply(coords[N:M,],mean) # mean of coordinates N to M
```

I need the average of several sets of coordinates, so I made this loop, which finds the mean of coordinates 1-4, 5-11 and 20-30.

```
N <- c(1, 5,20)
M <- c(4,11,30)
for ( i in 1:length(N) ) {
    sapply(coords[N(i):M(i),],mean)
}
```

How can I vectorize that loop? I've tried to pass a matrix to coords (`coords[NM,]`), but that doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: -1 because this is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and because you accepted an answer only half an hour after posting the question [LINK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5236)

Comment: What is not reproducible? I tried the code before pasting it here. I accepted the answer because it solved my problem. If I get a better one, I always change the accepted answer.

Comment: @GSee It could be any numeric data frame with >=30 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace your `sapply(x, mean)` by `colMeans(x)` in the sake of simplicity and efficiency.

Perhaps by a vector thinking you prefer to convert several variables (N and M) to a single vector - here array - when possible and simple.

```
N <- data.frame(from=c(1,5,20), to=c(4,11,30))
apply(N, 1, function(x) colMeans(coords[x[1]:x[2],]))
```